# Azure pipeline cron trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure DevOps pipeline in yaml format that I would like to run every 3 hours.

I configured the yaml file to have a cron trigger as follow:

```
schedules:
  - cron: '0 */1 * * *'
    displayName: Daily Trigger
    branches:
      include:
        - master
    always: true

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x'
      addToPath: true
  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install selenium

  - task: Pythonscript@0
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      scriptPath: './test.py'
```

But the pipeline does not trigger at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you see when you click here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-runs-view

Comment: `There are no scheduled runs for this week`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your branch name in cron schedule. If you have there a typo it could be a reason why it doesn't work.

I tested with this:

```yaml
schedules:
  - cron: '* */3 * * *'
    displayName: Daily Trigger
    branches:
      include:
        - master
    always: true


trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

And it works:

[image]

Can you try to re-add your pipeline?

Comment: I just updated my post, the only difference that we have, is that you declared a trigger and I didn't, could that be the problem? I will re-add my pipeline and see if it works

Comment: It should not affect. I just did it because O have more than 100 pipelines in that repo.

Comment: @NaydenVan Please check if you have `master` or `main` branch.

Comment: Solved. Just for demonstration in the pipeline I declared the master branch. My real pipeline had a typo in the branch name. Thats why it wasn't working. Thank you so much for opening my eyes onto this error. You are amazing

Comment: If you want to update your answer with your last comment I can up vote it

Comment: I just did it. Thanks for your nice words. I'm happy we solved this issue.